# Replace tags stored in database keeping the string between them

Tags: mysql

For example, if I have

```
<b>some king of #1 Text</b>
```

stored in a mysql table, is there a way to change it to

```
<h2>some king of #1 Text</h2>
```

without going to each row and manually changing it.?

In some cases [if possible] I need to replace

```
<p><b>some king of #1 Text</b></p><p>other text</p>
```

with

```
<h2>some king of #1 Text</h2><p>other text</p>
```

. I was thinking maybe sql expressions.

Comment: you mean just changing all `<b>` to `<h2>` (and same for closing tags) ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't natively support regular expression replacement, and indeed it would be really difficult to do reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function *if* your tags only look like `<b>` and `</b>` without other attributes, since this really just amounts to a simple string replacement action.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET thecolumn = REPLACE(thecolumn, '<b>', '<h2>');
UPDATE yourtable SET thecolumn = REPLACE(thecolumn, '</b>', '</h2>');
```

If your tags contain other attributes like `<b class='something'>` you are best off just to modify it at the time of output using an HTML parser.

#### Update after question was edited:

If you have the *exact pattern* `<p><b>...</b></p>` without extra whitespace, you can still use `REPLACE()`, but you will need to run this pair *before* the two listed above.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET thecolumn = REPLACE(thecolumn, '<p><b>', '<h2>');
UPDATE yourtable SET thecolumn = REPLACE(thecolumn, '</b></p>', '</h2>');
```

Anything beyond this in complexity will best be handled by modifying the HTML in application code with a proper HTML parser as I mentioned before.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. None of the tags have attributes. I added a bit more info to the question.

Comment: @DaedBaet and I added a bit more to the answer... this complicates it but still might be possible.

Comment: After looking at it, Michael, it looks like it will work perfect. I think my biggest issue is solved by replacing <p><b> [etc] before <b>... I've been making it more difficult than it really is. Thank you for your time.